# Setter annotation is not working in Java class

Tags: java, lombok

My workspace structure is like:

```
 package1
     Class A
 package 2
    Class B
```

The class A has all the annotations added to it:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Value
@Data
@ToString
@Builder
class A {
    int a,
    int b
}
```

But when I try to use `A.setA(1)` in class B I get error that setA is not a function defined.

I have included the following dependency in config:

```
LombokUtils = 1.1;
Lombok = 1.16.x;
```

Not sure what is getting wrong here. `@Setter` annotation is not working.

Comment: `A` is a class and those method are non-static, you should be using `a.setA` instead
BTW: `@Data` already contains `@Getter` & `@Setter` so you can remove `@Getter` & `@Setter` and it would still work

Comment: P.S Please always add imports into the code in post it helps other devs to understand what dependencies you are referring to

Comment: to complete what @Youans said, take a look at https://projectlombok.org/features/Value. Using '@Value' : all fields are made private and final by default, and setters are not generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a conflict between `@Value` (which helps creating immutable classes) and `@Setter` (which adds methods that mutates the class state).

Remove the `@Value` annotation, and you should have setters in class A.

Answer (score 2):

> `@Getter`

This tells lombok to make getters. But, `@Data` also does this, and `@Value` also does this. There is no point to this annotation; remove it.

> `@Setter`

This tells lombok to make setters **for all non-final fields** (spoiler: Your fields are final here, so no setters are made). But, `@Data` also does this - it also means: Make a setter for every non-final field. There is no point to this annotation; remove it.

> `@Value`

This tells lombok to make the class final, **to make all fields final**, to make all fields private, make a constructor that sets all fields, make a toString, make getters, and make hashcode and equals methods.

Because it makes all fields final, this makes `@Setter` do nothing.

> `@Data`

You should not annotate a class with both Data and Value: They are opposites. If you intend for those fields to be settable, you're looking for `@Data`, and not for `@Value`. Delete one of them.

> `@ToString`

Both Data and Value already do this; There is no point to this annotation; remove it.

> `@Builder`

That's not implied by anything else, so keep it.

I'm pretty sure you want:

```
@Data @Builder class Foo {
}
```

and nothing else. Actually, you have builder, so you may want an immutable class (so, no setters at all - you construct an instance and it is then not changable), in which case, you're looking for `@Value @Builder class Foo {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on lombok's reference [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value):

> @Value is the immutable variant of @Data; all fields are made private
> and final by default, and setters are not generated.

@Value creates immutable classes while @Setter makes classes mutable by adding setters.

**So in order to have setters remove @Value**.

check this out without @Value:

```
package com.samples.demo.pacakge1;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
//@Value
@ToString
public class A {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

and class B:

```
package com.samples.demo.package2;

import com.samples.demo.pacakge1.A;

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = A.builder().build(); //can't use A a=new A();
        a.setY(12);
        System.out.println(a.getY());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not working becasue in the class A you need to
`import lombok.Getter;` and `import lombok.Setter;`
Now in your B class you should be able to access the setter.
You can get more information [Here](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-generate-getters-and-setters-with-lombok/)

Answer (score 0):

change the visibility of the class A as public and try